# Taking the mean of every n elements in an array and converting MATLAB code to Python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

I am attempting to convert a MATLAB program to Python and have run into a snag with a certain loop: I have a 5868x3500 matrix comprising of 5868 daily observations the ratio of returns and volumes of 3500 stocks, this data is used to produce a measure of market liquidity by taking monthly averages the ratio of each stock's return over its volume. I have a 5868x1 vector called `Dummymonth` which assigns an integer to each month from 1 to 270, with ~22 trading days per month (`1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1... 2,2,2,2,2,2... 270,270,270`).

The loop I'm stuck on needs to convert the 5868x3500 matrix into a 270x3500 matrix by taking the monthly average according to the Dummymonth values (i.e. Basically taking the average of every 22 values).

I've tried converting the code as cleanly as possible (substituting MATLAB's `find()` function for Python's `.argwhere()`), but I am relatively new to Python (and MATLAB really) so the problems with the code do not seem immediately obvious to me.

Here is the section of MATLAB code I am trying to emulate:

```matlab
numberofmonth=Dummymonth(size(Ret,1));
i=1;
for di=1:numberofmonth
    v=find(Dummymonth==di);
    for j=1:size(Ret, 2)
        Amihud2(i,j)=nanmean(Amihud1(v,j));
    end
    i=i+1;
end
```

And here is what I have in Python:

```py
import numpy as np
Amihud2 = np.empty((270, len(Amihud1)))
for month_num in range(0, 270):
    v = np.argwhere(dummy == month_num)
    for i in range(1, len(Amihud1)):
        for j in range(1, len(Amihud1[0])):
            Amihud2[i][j] = np.mean(Amihud1[v][j])
```

The errors I am usually seeing are "index out of bounds errors".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one of the errors is related to Python's 0 indexing. If you loop over something and start at 1, you miss the first (index 0) values. Here is one solution (there are many):

```
#Create Dummy index
dummy =np.array([np.repeat(i,22) for i in np.arange(270)+1]).flatten()

#Make Dataset for example
dat = np.random.random((len(dummy),3500))

#Calculate average per month
dat2 = np.empty((270,3500))
i=-1
for m in np.unique(dummy):
    i=i+1
    dat2[i,:]=dat[dummy==m].mean(axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks! My reputation doesn't allow me to upvote, but I much appreciate the response. I'll incorporate your suggestions and get post back if I get subsequent errors.

Comment: Here is an improvement to your code: `dummy = np.repeat(np.arange(1, 271), 22)` is much more readable.

Comment: You don't need unique. You know what you put in: `np.arange(1, 271)`

Comment: When using `for m in np.arange(1, 271):` instead of `i` you can use `m - 1`

Comment: Thank you everyone for the replies! I tried running a code similar to @Rowan_Gaffney's, but it appears to have thrown another error: `IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 3500 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1`. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: make sure the masking array is the correct length to mask your data array. In my example, check the equivalent arrays as "dummy" and "dat" with dummy.shape and dat.shape. Your data array may be shorter than you think if you are only part way thru the last month.